# Error on loading the 64bit operating system on a 32 bit system

Tags: virtualbox

I am a new to virtual box environment. I installed virtualbox-4.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit system. Now i am trying to import a 64 bit operating system. I got the following error.

```
Failed to open a session for the virtual machine localvm.
VT-x is not available. (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX).


Result Code: 
NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005)
Component: 
Console
Interface: 
IConsole {db7ab4ca-2a3f-4183-9243-c1208da92392}
```

I tried to make my question clear but if its not clear any edits are welcome and help me to come out from this.... thank YOu

Comment: The error pretty much explains the issue -- [VT-x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Intel_virtualization_.28VT-x.29) is not available.

Comment: Can you explain what can be done to resolve this error

Comment: Troubleshoot to figure out what's causing it and fix whatever the cause is. Does the CPU support VT-x? Is it enabled in the BIOS? ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run 64-bit virtual machines on a 32-bit platform, you need hardware virtualization support. It is called VT-x for Intel processors, and AMD-V for AMD. It seems it isn't available on your system. Check the BIOS, it may have been turned off, or check if your processor indeed supports hardware virtualization.

Comment: ..and check the VM settings in virtualbox, if it's enabled for that virtual machine (should be by default i think).

Comment: I checked the Bios information its is as follows ....BIOS is upgradeable

Comment: It doesn't matter whether the BIOS can be upgraded or not. Look for "VT-x" or "AMD-V" in the BIOS settings. If you can't find them, then most probably your processor doesn't support HW virtualization.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this command: `egrep -i "vmx|svm" /proc/cpuinfo` to verify the presence of virtualization extensions.
You should also check your VMs settings under VM settings -> System -> Acceleration and check the first box.

In order to run a 64-bit guest on a 32-bit OS you are still required to have a 64-bit CPU with VMX/SVM. See [VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#intro-64bitguests)

Comment: Hi there, I tried to egrep -i "vmx|svm" /proc/cpuinfo i didnt get any output....

Comment: I also checked the VM settings but my Accleration is not activated.

Comment: No output indicates that your CPU doesn't support any virtualization features, but according to the vbox manual (link in post above) these features are required in order to run 64-bit guests. So I would say you have to replace your CPU.